# Tags input component with support for space in tagname

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tags, jsf-2.2, custom-component

I need an input field capable of taking tags with spaces in tagname like shown below:

[image]

I know that the [`<p:autoComplete multiple="true">`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml) supports taking tags, but it uses space to separate tags:

[image]

I'd like to include space in the tagname and use <kbd>;</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to advance to next tag. How can I create a new custom component, or customize the `<p:autoComplete>` for this? I'm using JSF 2.2 and PrimeFaces 3.2.

Comment: @BalusC When I type a splitter like';' or i press enter. I starts entering the following value.

Comment: @BalusC I need an `inputText`  to introduce emails addresses (loke OUTLOOK, Gmail, .....)

Comment: @BalusC New custom component or customize the `<p:autoComplete>` the solution that solves my problem.

Comment: @BalusC I use primefaces 3.2,

Comment: Can't you upgrade your PrimeFaces ?

Comment: As I can see that in PrimeFaces 5.0 you can include spaces in the tag and what submits a tag is the enter key.. so I think that's exactly what you want to achieve here. I'm not sure if in PF 3.2 it's different.

Comment: @HatemAlimam what is this tag ??

Comment: The same exact component you posted above, `<p:autoComplete multiple="true">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not rewrite/modify it's JavaScript functions (in autocomplete.js) ?

code & functions of interest :

***bindStaticEvents***

```
bindStaticEvents: function() {
        var $this = this;

        this.bindKeyEvents();

        this.dropdown.mouseover(function() {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
        }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
        }).mousedown(function() {
            if($this.active) {
                $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
            }
        }).mouseup(function() {
            if($this.active) {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');

                $this.search('');
                $this.input.focus();
            }
        }).focus(function() {
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-focus');
        }).blur(function() {
            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-focus');
        }).keydown(function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which;

            if(key === keyCode.SPACE || key === keyCode.ENTER || key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER) {
                $(this).addClass('ui-state-active');
            }
        }).keyup(function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which;

            if(key === keyCode.SPACE || key === keyCode.ENTER || key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER) {
                $(this).removeClass('ui-state-active');
                $this.search('');
                $this.input.focus();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        });
```

***bindKeyEvents***

```
bindKeyEvents: function() {
        var $this = this;

        this.currentText = this.input.val();
        this.previousText = this.input.val();

        //bind keyup handler
        this.input.keyup(function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode,
            key = e.which,
            shouldSearch = true;

            $this.previousText = $this.currentText;
            $this.currentText = this.value;

            // Cancel a possible long running search when selecting an entry via enter
            if (key === keyCode.ENTER || key === keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER) {
                if ($this.timeout) {
                    clearTimeout($this.timeout);
                }
                shouldSearch = false;
            }
            else if (key === keyCode.ESCAPE) {
                $this.hide();
                shouldSearch = false;
            }
            else if ((e.ctrlKey && key === 65) // ctrl+a
                || (e.ctrlKey && key === 67) // ctrl+c
                || key === keyCode.LEFT
                || key === keyCode.RIGHT
                || key === keyCode.TAB
                || key === 16 // keyCode.SHIFT
                || key === keyCode.HOME
                || key === keyCode.END
                || key === 18 // keyCode.ALT
                || key === 17 // keyCode.CONTROL
                || (key >= 112 && key <= 123)) { // F1-F12
                shouldSearch = false;
            }
            else if(key === keyCode.UP || key === keyCode.DOWN) {
                if($this.panel.is(':visible')) {
                    var highlightedItem = $this.items.filter('.ui-state-highlight');
                    if(highlightedItem.length) {
                        $this.displayAriaStatus(highlightedItem.data('item-label'));
                    }
                }

                shouldSearch = false;
            }
            else if($this.cfg.pojo && !$this.cfg.multiple && ($this.previousText !== $this.currentText)) {
                $this.hinput.val($(this).val());
            }

            if(shouldSearch) {
                var value = $this.input.val();

                if(!value.length) {
                    $this.hide();
                }

                if(value.length >= $this.cfg.minLength) {

                    //Cancel the search request if user types within the timeout
                    if($this.timeout) {
                        clearTimeout($this.timeout);
                    }

                    var delay = $this.cfg.delay;

                    if (value != '' && (key == keyCode.BACKSPACE || key == keyCode.DELETE)) {
                        delay = $this.cfg.deletionDelay;
                    }

                    $this.timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        $this.search(value);
                    }, delay);
                }
            }

        }).keydown(function(e) {
            var keyCode = $.ui.keyCode;

            if($this.panel.is(':visible')) {
                var highlightedItem = $this.items.filter('.ui-state-highlight');

                switch(e.which) {
                    case keyCode.UP:
                        var prev = highlightedItem.length == 0 ? $this.items.eq(0) : highlightedItem.prevAll('.ui-autocomplete-item:first');

                        if(prev.length == 1) {
                            highlightedItem.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
                            prev.addClass('ui-state-highlight');

                            if($this.cfg.scrollHeight) {
                                PrimeFaces.scrollInView($this.panel, prev);
                            }

                            if($this.cfg.itemtip) {
                                $this.showItemtip(prev);
                            }
                        }

                        e.preventDefault();
                        break;

                    case keyCode.DOWN:
                        var next = highlightedItem.length == 0 ? $this.items.eq(0) : highlightedItem.nextAll('.ui-autocomplete-item:first');

                        if(next.length == 1) {
                            highlightedItem.removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
                            next.addClass('ui-state-highlight');

                            if($this.cfg.scrollHeight) {
                                PrimeFaces.scrollInView($this.panel, next);
                            }

                            if($this.cfg.itemtip) {
                                $this.showItemtip(next);
                            }
                        }

                        e.preventDefault();
                        break;

                    case keyCode.ENTER:
                    case keyCode.NUMPAD_ENTER:
                        highlightedItem.click();

                        e.preventDefault();
                        e.stopPropagation();
                        break;

                    case 18: //keyCode.ALT:
                    case 224:
                        break;

                    case keyCode.TAB:
                        highlightedItem.trigger('click');
                        $this.hide();
                        break;
                }
            }
            else if (e.which == keyCode.TAB) {
                // clear pending search before leaving the field
                if ($this.timeout) {
                    clearTimeout($this.timeout);
                }
            }
        });
    },
```

***bindDynamicEvents***

```
 bindDynamicEvents: function() {
        var $this = this;

        //visuals and click handler for items
        this.items.bind('mouseover', function() {
            var item = $(this);
        if(!item.hasClass('ui-state-highlight')) {
            $this.items.filter('.ui-state-highlight').removeClass('ui-state-highlight');
            item.addClass('ui-state-highlight');

            if($this.cfg.itemtip) {
                $this.showItemtip(item);
            }
        }
    })
    .bind('click', function(event) {
        var item = $(this),
        itemValue = item.attr('data-item-value');

        if($this.cfg.multiple) {
            var itemDisplayMarkup = '<li data-token-value="' + item.attr('data-item-value') + '"class="ui-autocomplete-token ui-state-active ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden">';
            itemDisplayMarkup += '<span class="ui-autocomplete-token-icon ui-icon ui-icon-close" />';
            itemDisplayMarkup += '<span class="ui-autocomplete-token-label">' + item.attr('data-item-label') + '</span></li>';

            $this.inputContainer.before(itemDisplayMarkup);
            $this.multiItemContainer.children('.ui-helper-hidden').fadeIn();
            $this.input.val('').focus();

            $this.hinput.append('<option value="' + itemValue + '" selected="selected"></option>');
        }
        else {
            $this.input.val(item.attr('data-item-label')).focus();

            this.currentText = $this.input.val();
            this.previousText = $this.input.val();

            if($this.cfg.pojo) {
                $this.hinput.val(itemValue);
            }
        }

        $this.invokeItemSelectBehavior(event, itemValue);

        $this.hide();
    });
},
```

**Suggestions** : Replace `key === keyCode.SPACE` with `key === 188` (which is the code for `;`)

**Note** : It might have some side effects, especially if you are using autocomplete somewhere else and differently..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this jquery [plugin](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) that allows customization around the tags which can allow spaces (see [example page](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/examples.html)).

You'll want to create a composite component with an h:input, then apply the jquery plugin to it. That'll give you something similar to the language tags in stackoverflow.

The composite component would aggregate the hidden inputs that tagit generates using javascript and sets the value of an h:inputHidden component. Something like this:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:cc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<cc:interface shortDescription="TagIt wrapper">
    <cc:attribute name="val" type="java.lang.String" required="true" shortDescription="value" />        
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>

    <h:outputStylesheet library="cui" name="jquery.tagit.css" target="head" />
    <h:outputStylesheet library="cui" name="tagit.ui-zendesk.css" target="head" />

    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="cui" name="jquery-ui.min.js" target="head" />
    <h:outputScript library="cui" name="tag-it.min.js" target="head" />             

    <h:outputScript>                                
        $(function() {
            //Activate the tagit plugin with the allow spaces option. 
            //we insert the clientId to insure uniqueness of ids in case the component 
            //was used multiple times on the same page. We must escape JSF's column 
            //separator since it's considered a special character for jQuery
            var tagId = ("#" + "#{cc.clientId}:myTags".replace(/:/g, "\\:"));                           
            $(tagId).tagit({allowSpaces: true});                              

            //find the input element generated by the plugin and whenever it loses focus, 
            //update the hidden input with the values of all the tags separated by semi-columns
            //The hidden input is wired to the 'val' attribute and will feed the value to the backing bean             
            $("input[type='text'].ui-widget-content").blur(function() {                                                     
                var allTags = "";
                $('.tagit-hidden-field').each(function() {
                    allTags += $(this).val() + ";"                      
                });
                var hiddenInputId = ("#" + "#{cc.clientId}:tagValue".replace(/:/g, "\\:"));                                
                $(hiddenInputId).val(allTags);
            });
        });                
    </h:outputScript>

    <h:inputHidden id="tagValue" value="#{cc.attrs.val}"/>

    <p>Hit Enter or Comma to separate tags</p>

    <ul id="#{cc.clientId}:myTags">         
    </ul>

</cc:implementation>
```

You would then use it on the page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
    xmlns:cui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/cui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="form">      
        <cui:tagit val="#{page1.tags}" />                                   
        <h:commandButton value="Submit">
          <f:ajax execute="@form" render="output"/>
        </h:commandButton>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Added a working example that does exactly what you're asking for. Might want to remove the comments from the inline javascript as some versions of Mojarra don't like it.